# Class inheritance when is mapped to table c#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

Is it possible to create a class inheritance when one of the class is mapped to a table in a db? I'm trying to use this classes for different methods and I want to show only the info I need

I'm getting this error "Message": "Error.", "ExceptionMessage": "The column name  'Discriminator' is not valid.", "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace Someproject.Models
{

    [Table("Vo_User")]
    public class FirstClass
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string post { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondClass : FirstClass
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public Int32? Code { get; set; }
        public Int32? Company { get; set; }
        public string Flag_Approved { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdExample")]
        public virtual ICollection<ExampleClass> Example { get; set; }
    }

}
```

"Message": "Error.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "El nombre de columna 'Discriminator' no es válido.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @logix The problem is that I'm getting an error when I try to get the data...this is part from a web api project....


    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "Error.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The column name 'Discriminator' is not valid.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",

Comment: The obvious question is whether that is in fact, in the database.  I'd recommend following the tutorial.

Comment: You don't have a property that is named "Discriminator". So I guess your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the following article, assuming you are using EF6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

There's really too much here to include an entire tutorial, but the important part here is that the EF designer allows you to specify discriminators that decide which type of object in the inheritance chain a table row maps to.